# Stuck on order of integration problem

Tags: integration

I need to set up a double integral for both orders of integration and use the more convenient order to evaluate the integral $\int\int_{R}\frac{y}{1+x^2}dA$, where $R$ is the region bounded by $y=0, y=\sqrt{x}, x=4$.

I have tried setting it up, but am getting different answers so I must be wrong. I've been stuck on this for a while now!

**My work:** $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{y^2}\frac{y}{1+x^2}dxdy$, $\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{y}{1+x^2}dxdy$

They don't evaluate the same, but I can't tell where I'm going wrong!

Comment: I believe the first one in the "**My work**"-section is supposed to be
$$
\int_{0}^{2}\int_{y^2}^{4}\frac{y}{1+x^2}dxdy
$$
Remember, $x$ is _bigger_ than $y^2$ in the area you're integrating, this should be reflected in your limits.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that my second integral should say dydx instead of dxdy! My error was confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a picture.  To switch the order of integration, you need to integrate out from the curve to $x=4$:

$$\int_0^2 dy \, \int_{y^2}^4 dx \frac{y}{1+x^2}$$